# How to read json data using python from kafka topic in apache spark

Tags: json, pyspark, spark-streaming-kafka

I am new spark, Could you please let me know how to read json data using python from kafka topic in apache spark.
I tried following Code which worked for single line json but not for multiline json

```
*kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, k_host+':'+k_port, 'spark-streaming', {k_topic:1})
kafkaStream.pprint()
lines = kafkaStream.map(lambda row : row[1])*
```

Thanks.